# How to get the fill threshold of a particular partition

Tags: shell

I need help in alteration of script: i need to set threshold on particular partition.

my script :

```
for n in `df -h|awk {'print $5'}|awk -F% {'print $1'}`; do
        if [ $n -gt 85 ]
        then
            echo $n."iiiiiiiiiiii";
        endif
```

Pls help to resolve this. **85** is set for all but i need on particular partition.

Regards,
Riddhi

Comment: Thanks dogbane,I need to exclude particular partition form the all so how can i alter this command should i use cut command in it ??

Comment: Please post the complete unedited output of `df -h` and then tell us what you expect after processing with your script.

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work? Please provide **exact error messages.** Are you getting a syntax error about an unterminated `if`? That would be due to the `endif` which should read `fi` in Bourne heritage shells. PS: the semicolon after the echo is useless and you need a `done` to terminate the `for` loop.

Selecting a particular partition should work with

```
df -h /dev/your_partition_here | awk ...
```

Reading the `df`(1) manual (type `man df`) will provide plenty of details.

Comment: Glad to be of help. You should upvote helpful answers and accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: How can i exclude this partition form all, total having 19 partition and i want to exclude form all /cs (my partition)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `df -h` and then specify exactly what you are interested in.

Comment: @RIDDHI Done what exactly? Found a solution? Then please share it so everyone can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `awk` command to match the partition name. For example, if your partition is '`/some/path`', then your command would be:

```
for n in `df -h|awk '/\/some\/path/{print $5}'|awk -F% {'print $1'}`; do
        if [ $n -gt 85 ]
        then
            echo $n."iiiiiiiiiiii";
        fi
done
```

(You need to escape the forward slashes in the partition name.)

Comment: Why not simply provide the partition as argument to df? No messy escaping and useless line reading in awk.